# 40 percent of X's Y: Is the percentage about X or Y?

Tags: mathematics, double-possessives

> Some 40 percent of people's "first memory" happened at an age when it wasn't possible to create memories.

[Source](https://allthatsinteresting.com/first-memories-fake-study)

Context shows the percentage is about the people. The word memory, being singular, also indicates the percentage is about the people. Without context, would you be able to infer which is meant if we changed the sentence to:

> Some 40 percent of people's first **memories** ...

And what about this one:

> 20 percent of the countries' money came from tourism.

Is there any rule for the structure "n % of X's Y"?

Comment: X only modifies Y. It has no bearing on the calculation. So "40 percent of  memories" and "20 percent of the money" basically mean the same thing.

Comment: Does that mean the writer of the cited headline made a mistake?

Comment: No, it is still "40 percent of memories", where "memories" are being counted. *people's" just tells us whose memories are being counted, but the example does not count people.

Comment: If you read the article, you'll find that the percentage is about the people, not the memories. Here's an excerpt from the first lines: "Published in the journal Psychological Science, researchers conducted one of the largest surveys ever done on early memories and found that nearly 40 percent of people had a fictional first memory."

Comment: You should include such text in your question. Links are OK for reference, but pertinent information should be in the question.

Comment: Maybe it was written poorly, though in reality the applicable person to false first memory ratio is 1:1. Or person to first memory in fact.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the object of the preposition is

> **memories**

So many would understand it to mean "less than half of one's first memories".

If it is meant as you say, it might be

> For 40% of the people, their first memories...

The percentage is associated with the object of the preposition **of**.
A percentage **of** something.